# How do I get my drop down menu to select the genre and only display the songs of that genre on the JQuery table?

Tags: jquery, json, html-table, drop-down-menu

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "songlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "songs": \[
    {
      "title": "Hell Bells",
      "artist": "AC/DC",
      "genre": "Metal",
      "released": "1980"
    },
    {
      "title": "Megan's Piano",
      "artist": "Megan Thee Stallion",
      "genre": "Hip-Hop/Rap",
      "released": "2021"
    }
  ]
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<h1>Song List</h1>

<table id='table'>
  <!-- HEADING FORMATION -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Song Name</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>
        Genre
        <p id="demo" style="text-align: center;"></p>
        <select id="myselect" onchange="sunshine(this.value)">
          <option value="genre">Choose a Genre:</option>
          <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
          <option value="Metal">Metal</option>
          <option value="Hip-Hop/Rap">Hip-Hop/Rap</option>
          <option value="Dance/Electronic">Dance/Electronic</option>
          <option value="Alternative/Indie, Pop">Alternative/Indie, Pop</option>
          <option value="New Wave, Synthpop">New Wave, Synthpop</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>Year Released</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**jquery code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  $.getJSON("./package.json", function(data) {
    var song = '';
    // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
    $.each(data.songs, function sunshine(key, value) {
      //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING
      // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
      song += '<tr>';
      song += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
      song += '<td>' + value.artist + '</td>';
      song += '<td>' + value.genre + '</td>';
      song += '<td>' + value.released + '</td>';
      song += '</tr>';
    });
    //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE
    $('#table').append(song);
  });
});
```

I need to make a song list and display it on a table using the data from a json file. That data then needs to be sorted by a drop down menu of genres displayed in the table. When something from drop down menu is selected only the songs of that genre are displayed. I can get everything to work I just am not sure how to link the drop down menu selection to the displayed table. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First: I think in your `$.each` statement should be an anonymous function (without the name `sunshine`). Furthermore it is better, to prevent event handlers inline in the html code like `onchange` and define them in the JS code.

---

In my opinion it would be better, to append all songs initially (like your code already does) and use an separate event handler for the `change` event to show/hide them. For the filtering you could use a data attribute (maybe `data-genre`) and assign the genre value to it:

```js
song += '<tr data-genre="' + value.genre + '">';
```

By the way, it's easier to show and hide the rows, if they are in a table body:

```html
  </thead>

  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$('#table tbody').append(song);
```

To show and hide the rows you could use the data attribute and a CSS class (maybe `hidden`):

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
$('tr[data-genre="' + this.value + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
```

**Working example (initial list visible):**

(for demonstration i defined the JSON data as an array)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  var data = {
    "name": "songlist",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {},
    "songs": [{
      "title": "Hell Bells",
      "artist": "AC/DC",
      "genre": "Metal",
      "released": "1980"
    }, {
      "title": "Megan's Piano",
      "artist": "Megan Thee Stallion",
      "genre": "Hip-Hop/Rap",
      "released": "2021"
    }]
  };
  var song = '';
  // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
  $.each(data.songs, function(key, value) {
    //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING
    // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
    song += '<tr data-genre="' + value.genre + '">';
    song += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
    song += '<td>' + value.artist + '</td>';
    song += '<td>' + value.genre + '</td>';
    song += '<td>' + value.released + '</td>';
    song += '</tr>';
  });
  //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE
  $('#table tbody').append(song);

  $('#myselect').on('change', function() {
    $('tbody tr').addClass('hidden');

    if (this.value !== 'genre') {
      $('tr[data-genre="' + this.value + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('tbody tr').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Song List</h1>

<table id='table'>
  <!-- HEADING FORMATION -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Song Name</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>
        Genre
        <p id="demo" style="text-align: center;"></p>
        <select id="myselect">
          <option value="genre">Choose a Genre:</option>
          <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
          <option value="Metal">Metal</option>
          <option value="Hip-Hop/Rap">Hip-Hop/Rap</option>
          <option value="Dance/Electronic">Dance/Electronic</option>
          <option value="Alternative/Indie, Pop">Alternative/Indie, Pop</option>
          <option value="New Wave, Synthpop">New Wave, Synthpop</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>Year Released</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

---

If you want an empty list before you select a genre, you can simply add the class `hidden` after appending the songs:

```js
$('#table tbody').append(song);
$('tbody tr').addClass('hidden');
```

and delete the else statement in the `change` event handler:

```js
else {                  //remove that else statement
  $('tbody tr').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

**Working example (initial list hidden):**

(for demonstration i defined the JSON data as an array)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  var data = {
    "name": "songlist",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {},
    "songs": [{
      "title": "Hell Bells",
      "artist": "AC/DC",
      "genre": "Metal",
      "released": "1980"
    }, {
      "title": "Megan's Piano",
      "artist": "Megan Thee Stallion",
      "genre": "Hip-Hop/Rap",
      "released": "2021"
    }]
  };
  var song = '';
  // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
  $.each(data.songs, function(key, value) {
    //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING
    // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
    song += '<tr data-genre="' + value.genre + '">';
    song += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
    song += '<td>' + value.artist + '</td>';
    song += '<td>' + value.genre + '</td>';
    song += '<td>' + value.released + '</td>';
    song += '</tr>';
  });
  //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE
  $('#table tbody').append(song);
  $('tbody tr').addClass('hidden');

  $('#myselect').on('change', function() {
    $('tbody tr').addClass('hidden');

    if (this.value !== 'genre') {
      $('tr[data-genre="' + this.value + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Song List</h1>

<table id='table'>
  <!-- HEADING FORMATION -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Song Name</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>
        Genre
        <p id="demo" style="text-align: center;"></p>
        <select id="myselect">
          <option value="genre">Choose a Genre:</option>
          <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
          <option value="Metal">Metal</option>
          <option value="Hip-Hop/Rap">Hip-Hop/Rap</option>
          <option value="Dance/Electronic">Dance/Electronic</option>
          <option value="Alternative/Indie, Pop">Alternative/Indie, Pop</option>
          <option value="New Wave, Synthpop">New Wave, Synthpop</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <th>Year Released</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```